# Need to remove extra space at bottom of div

Tags: html, css

There is space appearing after my image in my page (the red area in the code snippet below). The green div containing more content should be right up to the bottom of the image.

My aim is to fill the green div with hidden content, and when I click the image it will appear showing more information.

```css
.pp-post {
  color: #ffffff;
  background-color: red;
 margin: 0 auto;
  padding: 0px;
 max-width: 100%;
 position: relative;
}

.pp-post-item:hover > p {
 visibility: visible;
}

.pp-post-title {  
  font-size: 3em !important;
  font-family: Sanchez;
  position: absolute;
  visibility: hidden;
  top: 40%;
  left: 50%;  
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
}

.pp-arrow-down {  
  font-size: 2em !important;
  position: absolute;
  visibility: hidden;
  top: 60%;
  left: 50%;  
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
}

.pp-post-container {
  background-color:green;
}

.pp-post-main {
  margin: 0px;
  padding: 0px;
}

.pp-post-content {
  width: 70%;
  margin: auto;  
}

.pp-post-video {

}

.pp-post-left, .pp-post-right {
  display: inline-block;
  margin: 0px;
  width: 45%;
}

.pp-post-testimonials {
  background-color: #fff;
}
```

```html
<div class="pp-post">
     <div class="pp-post-item">
        <img src=" http://www.staging1.prosperopictures.com/wp-content/uploads/2017/08/a-dangerous-method-banner.jpg" />
        <p class="pp-post-title">Movie Title</p>
        <p class="pp-arrow-down">subtitle</p>
 </div>
</div>
<div id="pp-post" class="pp-post-container">
  <div id="pp-post-main" class="pp-post-main">
    <div id="pp-post-content" class="pp-post-content">
      <div id="pp-post-video" class="pp-post-video"></div>
      <div id="pp-post-left" class="pp-post-left">
        <div></div>
        <div></div>
        <div></div>
        <div></div>
        <div></div>
      </div>
      <div id="pp-post-right" class="pp-post-right">
        <div></div>
        <div></div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>   
  <div id="pp-post-testimonials" class="pp-post-testimonials">  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: I don't see any spacing in that snippet

Comment: Did you try using your web browser's development window to see what settings impact the spacing?

Comment: Did you consider using `absolute` positioning?

Comment: Yeah, in Chrome, `absolute` positioning, `z-index` at 999 and `width` 100% should get you going.

Comment: hmmm that don't seem to work for me.

Comment: Your html structure is not proper as you expect output still you want solution then give height in `pp-post-container` class.

Comment: Ah man I thought it worked, but it didn't I can't set a specific height on that because when the window resizes smaller the image shrinks, but div stays the same height.